# Show $f(x) =x-\dfrac{1}{2}(1+\log(x)) $ for $p\geq 1$ and $x\in(0,+\infty) $ is in $L^p$, and find value of $p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

How to show following function lies in $L^p$ space?
Actually, I have to find condition on $p$ so that this function belongs to $L^p$ space:

$$f(x) =x-\dfrac{1}{2}(1+\log(x)),\ \text{ for }\ p\geq 1\ \text{ and }\ x\in(0,+\infty) $$

I am not able to integrate
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|^p dx =\int_{0}^{\infty}\left| x-\dfrac{1}{2}(1+\log(x))\right|^p dx $$

and show that it is finite. [Show that the following function $f \in L_p$ if and only if $p=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924849/show-that-the-following-function-f-in-l-p-if-and-only-if-p-2)

Comment: It is in none of those spaces. Your function is continuous and from a certain point on monoton increasing (not even bounded).

Comment: But answer is p=2

Comment: Have you written the correct function and domain?

Comment: Also the question you link seems to have nothing to do with the question you ask. The function you want to integrate is completely different or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that
$$
\left| {f(x)} \right| =f(x) \ge \frac{x}{2}
$$
for all $x>0$. Hence,
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\left| {f(x)} \right|^p dx}  \ge \frac{1}{{2^p }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {x^p dx}  = \frac{1}{{2^p (p + 1)}}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to  + \infty } w^{p + 1}  =  + \infty 
$$
for any $p\geq 1$. Thus, $f$ *is not* in $L^p((0,+\infty))$ for any $p\geq 1$.

Comment: How have you got |f(x)|>x/2

Comment: $f(x) - \frac{x}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(x - \log x - 1)$, and you can check by elementary function analysis that $(0,+\infty) \ni x \mapsto x - \log x - 1$ has a global minimum at $x=1$ and its value is $0$. Thus, $f(x)-\frac{x}{2} \geq 0$. It also follows that $
f(x) \ge \frac{x}{2} > 0 \Rightarrow \left| {f(x)} \right| = f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}(x-\log(x))$ is not in $L^p((0;\infty))$ for $p\geq 1$. Note that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1+1/x)>1/2$, thus our function is not bounded and we have $f(x) \geq f(1)=1/2$ for all $x\in (1;\infty)$. Hence, $f\notin L^p((0;\infty))$ for any $p\geq 1$.

Comment: Sorry , I have written f(x) in correctly now can you tell.

Comment: Here,$f'(x) =1-\dfrac{1}{2x}$ So,$f'(x) <0$  if x<1/2 and f'(x)>0 if x>1/2

Comment: Your new function grows even faster, so it still is not in any $L^p$.